# Opening file, editing, save, exit, open, edited version opens?

Tags: excerpt, quick-edit

How would you go about editing a file that you have inserted in a page on your website, saving it then exiting the file after editing then opening it up again with the editing that I have done before saving and exiting? I am wondering more about an excel file that I have inserted. My website is zistrrr.wordpress.com - database (pw - 123). I have no idea how to do it which is why I am asking.

Comment: it is very uncear what you ask, but seems like the right place to ask it is wordpress.com support

Answer (score -1):

If the document (Excel spreadsheet?) is inserted into a post/page, then that file is a 'Media' item, and the content is as it existed when you upload/inserted it.

If you want a dynamic document, then you could use something like DropBox or Google Drive to contain the file, giving permissions to anyone that has the link, and insert a link to that DropBox/Drive file. Then, any changes you make to the file (as stored in DropBox/Drive) will be available to visitors when they click on the link.  They will have to have a Dropbox/Drive account though.

You might be able to FTP a new version of the file to the file/folder equivalent of the URL for the uploaded Media item. Haven't tried this, but it should work.